# Getting Dynamic UIColor from SwiftUI Color (light and dark mode)

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

It is possible through an easy initialiser to get the UIColor from a SwiftUI Color as follows:

```
let primary = UIColor(Color("primary"))
```

I added the Color with a light and dark mode in an Asset Catalogue.
If `primary`is used in UIKit Code it unfortunately only gives me the light mode Version and does not dynamically change the color for dark mode.

I do not know, how to get the dark and light mode color from a Color to write my own extension as a bridge.

Is there a solution or do you always start with UIColors and bridge it into SwiftUI Code? The project is still heavily based on UIKit, but new views are written in SwiftUI.

Comment: Why `UIColor(named: )` does not work for you?

Comment: We have a Design System in place, which declares it colors right now with the ```Color``` class. We would have to write duplicate code in our architecture right now. Do you know a possible way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think what you want is possible. To achieve that you needed an initializer of `Color` that takes a light and dark variant and a way to resolve to a `cgColor` given a certain interface style (both not possible afaik). But your common ground could be the color name of your color from the asset catalogue and you could derive your SwiftUI/UIKit colors from the identifier.

```
struct ColorId: RawRepresentable, Equatable, Hashable {
    let rawValue: String

    init(_ rawValue: String) {
        self.init(rawValue: rawValue)
    }

    init(rawValue: String) {
        self.rawValue = rawValue
    }

    static let primaryText = ColorId("asset_name_of_primary_text_color")
}

extension ColorId {
    var color: Color { Color(rawValue) }
    var uiColor: UIColor? { UIColor(named: rawValue) }
}

struct SomeView: View {
    let textColor = ColorId.primaryText
    var body: some View { 
        Text("Text")
            .foregroundColor(textColor.color)  
    }
}

final class SomeUIView: UILabel {
    private let textColorId: ColorId

    init(textColorId: ColorId) {
        self.textColorId = textColorId
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        self.textColor = textColorId.uiColor
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) { fatalError("need a color id") }
}
```

Then you pass around your color ids and get the `UIColor` or `Color` values when you need them. If you use something like [RSwift](https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift) you could also just pass around the `ColorResource`'s.